# How to scroll a webview when the page finish loading

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-webview, runnable

here's what I'm trying to achieve: I assemble a local html page with some  tags and internet resources in it, and then load the html page webpage with WebView, and there's a "View More" button at the end of the page, when somebody clicks the button, I'll re-assemble the html page(with old data and new data, like refreshing twitter to load more twits) and have the WebView load it again. But as the user has scrolled to certain location when he clicks the button so I'd like to let the WebView to scroll to the very point where the user was before he clicks the button.

And here's what do by now, I create a WebViewClient and implements:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.scrollTo(last_X, last_Y);
}
```

It does not work as I expect it to, I have 2 concerns, guys please help me out:
1. this callback function does not work all the time. for most of the time, it works, but sometimes, for unknown reasons, it just does not work.
2. even if it works, it's not exactly what I want. as I mentioned, the html page contains some internet resources like

```
<a href='whateversite/whateverimage'><img src='whateversite/whateverimage'></img></a>
```

So the scrollTo function only got called when all images are loaded, it takes too much time and it's unnecessary, is there any way to start scrolling when the page is loaded but before all other resources got loaded? Per say, as long as webview.getContentHeight() > 0, it's OK to scroll.

Apologize for my poor english that I'll have to use load of words to try to make myself clear.

Guys, please halp~

Comment: WebViewClient has a callback onLoadResource() as explained here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @Chris have read about it but have not tried it yet. according to the descriptions, this will be called each time some resource is loaded, which means if I have 100 images in the page, this would be called 100 times, I'm afraid this might introduce performance problems if I have too many resources within the page. But I'd like to give it a try and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but it also means that you can detect when the text content has finished loading .. Just a thought . But there should be another graceful way to do it .

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        view.scrollTo(last_X, last_Y);
    }
});
```